# Which .less files I should import to start working with Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I create a custom.less file. Which files I should import (@import) to start working with Bootstrap?

How to get started with Bootstrap and LESS?? I can't find any tutorials...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion, before you kill yourself trying to get LESS to compile with Bootstrap, just set that folder aside for a bit and create a test project to get LESS working. Start like this:

1. Download and install [node](http://nodejs.org/)
2. Create a folder called something like "less-build" just to get this working
3. In windows, shift + right click (not sure what mac is) and select "open command window here". Type `npm install less -g` and hit enter to install LESS "globally" on your computer
4. Now type "npm install less" to install LESS "locally". If all is well you should see a folder called "node_modules" inside the less-build folder. If you click into node_modules you will see a folder for less.
5. Next, in the less-build folder create a file called styles.less. Inside that file add the following code:

`@backgroundColor:   #900;`

```
.block {
  background: @backgroundColor;
}
```

1. Save the file, close it.
2. Now, again in the command prompt type the following:

`lessc --compile styles.less > styles.css`

1. If all is well you should see the file styles.css. Open it and confirm that there is valid css in the file.

If that works, open the Bootstrap folder and find the less folder, you'll find a file called bootstrap.less. Use the process I described on bootstrap.less. This should give you a head start.

Answer (score 2):

#### You'll need just a few things:

- Bootstrap's .css and .js files
- The less.js file
- jquery.js

#### Linking them to your site:

To help optimize your website, take advantage of a few content delivery networks (CDNs) that are already out there.  The following lines will get you bootstrap and jquery.

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Since there isn't a Less CDN, you will need to download the less.js file [here](http://lesscss.org/), and then serve it up through your Static Media along with your custom .less file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/less-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/custom.less">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can download Bootstrap LESS files from [GitHub](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/tree/master/less).

Each files are often named like its corresponding component, check [the Bootstrap component's list](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/getting-started.html).

So, you can import files which are necessary for your need.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

Clone or download the content of the Twitter Bootstrap repository: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/

Then import `less/bootstrap.less`, and optionally `less/responsive.less`. With that, all mixins and variables defined by Twitter Bootstrap are available in your own LESS file.